# How to pass a value obtained by pressing a button to another file python

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
import weekly_plan
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
     '''
     skip
     '''
     def OpenExtractData(self):
        self.cb_year = QComboBox(self.dialog)
        self.cb_year.resize(160, 32)
        self.cb_year.move(160, 72)
        for year in range(2014,2061): self.cb_year.addItem(str(year))

        self.btn_start = QPushButton("시작", self.dialog)
        self.btn_start.move(30, 240)
        self.btn_start.resize(280,64)
        self.btn_start.clicked.connect(self.start)

    def start(self):
        target = self.cb_year.currentText()
        print(f"year : {target}")

        '''
        # 'target' values must be forwarded to 'weekly_plan.py' file.
        # This is where the 'weekly_plan.py' file should be executed.
        '''
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are currently two questions. The first one is that the value is not being passed to another file. When I press the button as written in the annotated part, I want to deliver the obtained value to another file. 
The second is The 'weekly_plan' file should be executed when the 'main' file is pressed, but when the 'main' file is executed, the 'weekly_plan' file is executed without pressing the button. 'import' at the top of the 'main' file immediately invokes function 'print' in the 'weekly_plan' file

```
# weekly_plan.py
.
.
print("run weekly_plan.py)
# year = 2021
'''
'year' value received from 'main.py'
'''
```

Comment: You can't "pass a value to another file". That's not how python works. When you import a .py file as a module, all code in that file is executed immediately. What you can do is put the code that you want to execute from the other file when the button is pressed in a function (`my_func`, say) with `target` as input parameter and call that in `MainWindow.start` via `weekly_plan.my_func(target)`.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I was able to get out of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as passing values between files. What you want to do is pass the desired values as arguments to a funtion defined and declared inside your `weekly_plan` module and imported to your `main` method which will "orchestrate" the way in which your program will be executed. e.g.

```
 def start(self):
    target = self.cb_year.currentText()
    desired_func(target) # desired_func has been imported from your weekly_plan module
```

Thus said you should import only the desired methods in your main file as so: `from my_weekly_plan import desired_func, other_func, etc_func` . If you import your module as a whole, any code in its `global scope` (outside methods or classes) will be executed on import.

Comment: I didn't find it anywhere, but I didn't think it would be an unusual way. It's dangerous to be clumsy in knowing multiple languages. Thank you for the information. It's been a great help.